# having trouble outputting an answer to a text file

Tags: python

I can't seem to output what I need to this text file. Basically I have to take bowlers from a text file and their scores, and output their name, their score, and if it's "Perfect" "Above average" or "Below Average" this is my code so far.

```
bowler_scores = {}
infile = open('bowlingscores.txt', 'r')
for line in infile:
    if line.strip().isalpha():
        names = line.strip()
    elif line.strip().isdigit():
        scores = int(line)
        bowler_scores[names] = scores
total = sum(bowler_scores.values())
num_scores = len(bowler_scores.values())
def my_avg(x, y):
    average = float(x/y)
    return average
my_avg(total, num_scores)
infile.close()

outfile = open('output.txt', 'w')
for x, y in bowler_scores.items():
    a = str(x)
    b = str(y)
    if y == 300:
        outfile.write('{} {} Perfect/n'.format(a, b))
    elif y > my_avg(total, num_scores):
        outfile.write('{} {} Above average'.format(a, b))
    elif y < my_avg(total, num_scores):
        outfile.write('{} {} Below average'.format(a, b))
```

I can't figure out how to make the answers print out into another text file. I've seen someone ask about the same problem but in the answers given they just printed it instead of outputting it into a text file. Help please?

Comment: What do you mean by `print out into another text file`?

Comment: So what happens when you run the code? How far does it get? What goes wrong? Have you narrowed it down to which line isn't working?

Comment: close the `outfile` using `outfile.close()`

Comment: Why would you need to close a file before it was opened?

Comment: That code _should_ write the answers to output.txt, although you should end each format string with the newline character `\n` (**not** `/n`). And you _should_ close outfile when you've written all the data to it, although that's not essential as the file will get closed when the program terminates. There are a few other odd things in your code. 1) You strip each input line twice. 2) Just before you close infile you calculate the average, but you don't store it, and then you recalculate the average twice for each bowler even though the average doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bowler_scores = {}
for line in open('bowlingscores.txt', 'rb'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.isalpha():
        name = line.strip()
        bowler_scores[name] = [] #1
    elif line.isdigit():
        score = int(line)
        bowler_scores[name].append(score) #2

def avg(x, y):
    return x/float(y) 

total = sum([sum(scores) for scores in bowler_scores.values()]) #3
num_scores = sum(len(value) for value in bowler_scores.values()) #4
total_avg = avg(total, num_scores) # 5

output = open('output.txt','wb')
for name, scores in bowler_scores.items(): #6
    bowler_avg = avg(sum(scores),len(scores)) #7
    if sum(scores) == 60: 
        output.write('{0} {1} Perfect\r\n'.format(name, scores))
    elif bowler_avg > total_avg: #8
        output.write('{} {} Above average\r\n'.format(name, scores)) #9
    elif bowler_avg < total_avg:
        output.write('{} {} Below average\r\n'.format(name, scores))
output.close()
```

Your code had some small problems:

1. You first have to create the bowler in the dict, with a empty list
   where you will put the scores
2. Then append the scores to this list
3. To calculate the total I've used a [list compression](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), I sum the scores for each bowler, then sum the sum of them.
4. Also using a list compression to calculate the size of scores
5. You can assign the avg in a variable to reuse it again
6. use more descriptive name
7. calculate the avg of score of the bowler
8. check if the avg is greater or lesser than the avg
9. you can use directly the items, they will be converted to strings, no need using str()

---

If there's just one score for each player here's the code:

```
for line in open('bowlingscores.txt', 'rb'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.isalpha():
        name = line.strip()
    elif line.isdigit():
        score = int(line)
        bowler_scores[name] = score

...

total = sum(bowler_scores.values())
num_scores = len(bowler_scores.values())

...

output = open('output.txt','wb')
for name, score in bowler_scores.items():
    if score == 300:
       output.write('{0} {1} Perfect\r\n'.format(name, score))
    elif score > total_avg:  #8
        output.write('{} {} Above average\r\n'.format(name, score))
    elif score < total_avg:
        output.write('{} {} Below average\r\n'.format(name, score))
output.close()
```

Comment: How did you figure that there were multiple scores for each bowler, or is that just a guess? :)

Comment: I guess because the use of word scores in the, if there jsut one score it will still work, I'll complement with a simpler code just in case.

Comment: Also note that the OP wants the answers printed to a file, not the console.

Comment: Oh yeah. I'm using python via web, can't use write functions. But i'll add it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much @f.rodrigues ! It was supposed to be built for one score sorry for not being clear. I learned a lot from this code though!